# How to hide facebook post link/caption parameter from facebook javascript sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook JavaScript SDK to post on different Facebook's users Pages, from my custom HTML form,

> My HTML FORM contains Following fields

```
title=>textbox, 
Link url=>textbox, 
picture=>textbox, 
message=>textarea
```

but the issue I'm facing is that when user did not entered LINK URL in field(blank), and entered Picture URL in picture URL fieldbox then facebook showing PICTURE HOST name in wall instead showing blank or no link URL / picture URL.
[image]

CODE which I am using for post my status on pages

```
FB.api('/' + d + '/feed', 'post', {
                                message: my_message,
                                link: url,
                                name: title,
                                picture: picUrl,
                                description: desc,
                                access_token: b.access_token
                            }, function (a) {
                                if (!a || a.error) {
                                    alert('Error occured')
                                } else {
                                    alert('Message Posted Successfully.')
                                }
                            })
```

> **link: url**
>
> **picture: picURL**

I tried to submit by comment "link" parameter but still facebook showing picture host URL address on wall.

so i need to know how to stop showing picture host URL address on wall if user did not submit link URL

Comment: Try the `caption` parameter. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts

Comment: Facebook says "Post caption (can only be used if link is specified)" if Link is not specified then picture URL shown on wall?

Comment: Well it also says that `picture` can only be used if `link` is given.

Comment: thanks for your help, but my problem is that i dont want to show any type of URL until user input URL in specified fields. But i could not getting solution from your link provided above.

Comment: For a normal post, you can either only post a message, or a message and a link – and that link could have description, thumbnail etc. Message and picture only, without a link, is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the Facebook post you can refer this link as an Caption you just need to keep some space into the Caption Parameter. If you are using string.empty then it will print the you IP Address/Domain Name.

Here i am providing you the sample Code for that...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            //Get your Facebook API Key from Web.config
            appId: '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FB_API_KEY"].ToString() %>',
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });
    };

    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

you need to create div to add the script into it.

Now, I am Calling the postToFacebook() function from the ServerSide, you can do that as per your requirement. So, Here is the function of that.

```
function postToFacebook() {

    var POST_NAME = "Post Name";
    var POST_DESCRIPTION = "Post Description";
    var POST_MESSAGE = "";


    //Here I am Leaving some space in the Caption to avoid link name
    var POST_CAPTION = "  ";


    var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { body: body, message: POST_MESSAGE, caption: POST_CAPTION, name: POST_NAME, description: POST_DESCRIPTION, picture: document.getElementById('hfImageURL').value }, function (response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    //alert(response.error);
                    alert('Image is not posted.');
                } else {
                    alert('Image is posted.');
                }
            });
        }
    }, { scope: 'offline_access,publish_stream' });
}
```

I am storing the Image URL into the HiddenField having ID hfImageURL, and give that to the picture property of the Post.

So that's it you can check that code... Working fine for me...

Have a Nice DAY...